# Rollup Typescript Error: dts is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollup

I'm trying to setup a React Component library with Rollup, but every time I try to build the app with `rollup -c`, I get the following error: `

```
[!] TypeError: dts is not a function
TypeError: dts is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\xyz\rollup.config.js:32:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
    at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:438:15)
```

Here are my files:

**rollup.config.js**

```
const resolve = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve')
const commonjs = require('@rollup/plugin-commonjs')
const typescript = require('@rollup/plugin-typescript')
const dts = require('rollup-plugin-dts')

const packageJson = require('./package.json')

module.exports = [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: 'dist/esm/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
]
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx"
  ],
  "rootDir": "./src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Default
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    // Added
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true
  }
}
```

and **package.json**

```
 "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.3.6",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.1.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.1.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^23.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^9.0.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.5",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^23.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.10",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^29.2.2",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^3.2.3",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Initially, I tried putting in all imports in ES6 way: `import xyz from 'xyz'`, but that gave me rollup error:

`RollupError: Node tried to load your configuration file as CommonJS even though it is likely an ES module. To resolve this, change the extension of your configuration to ".mjs", set "type": "module" in your package.json file or pass the "--bundleConfigAsCjs" flag.`

I also tried passing `dts` as `plugins: [dts]` instead of `plugins: [dts()]`

But that obviously broke when building the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days around juggling Dementevms's answer, the following worked for me:

1. Followed Dementevm's steps.
2. Converted the code from ES5 to ES6 with changing the

```
const resolve = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve')
const commonjs = require('@rollup/plugin-commonjs')
const typescript = require('@rollup/plugin-typescript')
const dts = require('rollup-plugin-dts')
```

to

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts'
```

and `module.exports = []` to `export default []`

3. Changed the rollup file extension from `rollup.config.js` to `rollup.config.mjs`

Comment: Note: If you rename your `rollup.config.js` to `rollup.config.mjs` you don't have to add `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, but if you want to keep `.js` extension you have to add it.

Comment: Yep right, I noticed that afterwards, I forgot to change it here, thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

Easily fixed by using `default`...

```
const dts = require('rollup-plugin-dts')
...
{
    input: './build/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/types.d.ts', format: 'es' }],
    plugins: [dts.default()],
}
```

Comment: This solution do not resolve correctly this issue

Answer (score 4):

I removed

```
const packageJson = require('./package.json')
```

And just inserted

```
{
    file: "dist/cjs/index.js",
    format: "cjs",
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  {
    file: "dist/esm/index.js",
    format: "esm",
    sourcemap: true,
  },
```

Remove --bundleConfigAsCjs from packagejson, use "rollup -c"
I initial install: npm i -D @types/react typescript @rollup/plugin-node-resolve @rollup/plugin-commonjs @rollup/plugin-typescript rollup-plugin-dts

Comment: This did not work for me. but it provided a base for the real solution for me

Answer (score 0):

May you need to try this

```
import { dts } from "rollup-plugin-dts";
```